# Showing a system of two ODEs is equivalent to a single ode.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I am trying to show that the system of two real ODEs is equivalent to a single complex differential equation.

The real system is given by $$\dot{p} = -kq$$ $$\dot{q} = kp$$ note $k$ is a constant different from $0$.

I must show that this equivalent to some complex differential equation in $z(t) = p(t)+iq(t)$.

I think the single DE in $z$ is given by $$\ddot{z} +kz = 0$$
Since we can write $q = -\frac{\dot{p}}{k}$ from the first equation and putting this into the second equation yields $\ddot{p}+k^2p = 0$.

Also from the second equation, $p = \frac{\dot{q}}{k}$, putting this into the top equation gives $\ddot{q}+k^2q = 0 \iff i\ddot{q} + ik^2q = 0$.

Comment: Yes.  So it's $\ddot{z} + k^2 z = 0$, not $k$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \dot{p}+i\dot{q} &= -kq+ikp \\
  &= ik(p+qi) \\
  \dot{z} &= ikz \\
  z(t) &= (a+bi) e^{ikt} \\
  p(t) &= a\cos kt-b\sin kt \\
  q(t) &= a\sin kt+b\cos kt
\end{align*}

where $a+bi$ is the integration constant.